# percent sign in PHP string

Tags: php, string, echo

I want to fire a query on database:

```
$query="SELECT field1 from table_name where field2 like '%".$_REQUEST['var1']."%'";
```

Page is showing **500 internal server error**.

At the time of debugging, I echo *$query*.
It was like:

```
SELECT field1 from table_name where field2 like 'value_of_var1%'
```

Where does the first percent sign has gone?
I searched on internet some said i have to put double percent sign(%%) in order to escape percent sign. If so, then why does the second percent sign doesn't need to be escaped?

This code(query) is executing in AJAX page, in order to debug i opened that AJAX page via URL.
It is showing perfect result

```
SELECT field1 from table_name where field2 like '%value_of_var1%'
```

But when page is called via AJAX it showing without first percent sign.
Can you please help me to understand what really the problem is?

Comment: You need to urlencode your query, since '%' is already the "start-code" of any urlencoded char. `%20` for example would turn into a whitespace.

Comment: Try this simpler form `$query = "SELECT field1 from table_name where field2 like '%{$_REQUEST['var1']}%";`. This way you don't have to deal with string concatenation.

Comment: Look at the HTML source code of the webpage in your browser. How is your query displayed there? Do you still notice missing characters?

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error specifically when the query is executed, you should check your error logs (or turn on error reporting and display_errors) and review the full error text. The query as displayed by `echo` may not be what you want, but it shouldn't be generating a server error, either; there could be more happening here than meets the eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your response.
My problem was, `$_REQUEST['var1']` was a number.
%number is parsed under HTML.
For error 500, It was mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value to a variable.

```
$variable = $_REQUEST['var1'];  
$query = "SELECT field1 from table_name where field2 like '%".$variable."%'";
```

This query has been tested and its working.

Comment: DON'T use this without sanitizing! This makes it as simple as a few quotes to dump the entire DB!